# Why ActiveX Command button does not run all codes in my VBA UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a complete novice at Excel VBA and I am currently attempting a project on Excel VBA. I have created a UserForm that would allow the user to enter data onto the Excel Sheet by completing the fields in the UserForm. I have tested all the codes individually and they have worked fine.

For the user to access the UserForm, I have added an ActiveX Command Button on a separate sheet on the same workbook. However, when accessing the UserForm from the ActiveX Command Button, some of the codes do not run (mainly the code that flags out the duplicate entry, as well as the code that generates serial numbers).

Where did I go wrong in my code?

This is my code to adding new data as well as the code to flag out duplicate entries. When opening the UserForm from the ActiveX Command Button, adding new data works fine but it does not flag out duplicate entries in the data. (However, testing the code itself in VBA works perfectly fine).

```
Private Sub cmdAddNewCustomer_Click()
Dim count As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lCustomerID As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Customer Data")
'find first empty row in database
lrow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", searchorder:=xlRows, _
    Searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    
lCustomerID = txtCustomerID

count = 0

With ws
    For currentrow = 1 To lrow
        If lCustomerID = Cells(currentrow, 1) Then
           count = count + 1
        End If
    
    If count > 1 Then
        .Cells(currentrow, 1).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 2).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 3).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 4).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 5).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 6).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 7).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 8).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 9).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 10).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 11).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 12).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 13).Value = ""
        .Cells(currentrow, 14).Value = ""
        MsgBox ("CustomerID already exists!")
    End If
    
    If count = 0 Then
        .Cells(lrow, 1).Value = Me.txtCustomerID.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 2).Value = Me.txtCustomerName.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 3).Value = Me.cboCustomerStatus.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 4).Value = Me.txtContactPerson.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 5).Value = Me.cboDepartment.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 6).Value = Me.txtPosition.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 7).Value = Me.cboRoleType.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 8).Value = Me.txtofficeHP1.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 9).Value = Me.txtOfficeHP2.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 10).Value = Me.txtMobileHP1.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 11).Value = Me.txtMobileHP2.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 12).Value = Me.txtEmail1.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 13).Value = Me.txtEmail2.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 14).Value = Me.txtEmail3.Value
    End If
Next currentrow
End With
'clear the data
Me.txtCustomerName.Value = ""
Me.cboCustomerStatus.Value = ""
Me.txtContactPerson.Value = ""
Me.cboDepartment.Value = ""
Me.txtPosition.Value = ""
Me.cboRoleType.Value = ""
Me.txtofficeHP1.Value = ""
Me.txtOfficeHP2.Value = ""
Me.txtMobileHP1.Value = ""
Me.txtMobileHP2.Value = ""
Me.txtEmail1.Value = ""
Me.txtEmail2.Value = ""
Me.txtEmail3.Value = ""

End Sub
```

This is the code to generate serial numbers. (Same problem, does not work when accessed via ActiveX Command Button but works fine when tested individually in VBA).

```
Sub FindCustomerID()
Dim lastrow
Dim lastnum As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Customer Data")
If Me.cboCountry = "" Or Me.txtCustomerName = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

serialno = 1

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

CountryCode = UCase(Left(Me.cboCountry, 3))
CustomerCode = UCase(Left(Me.txtCustomerName, 10))

'assemble them into CustomerID
CustomerID = CountryCode & CustomerCode & serialno

For currentrow = 2 To lastrow
    If CustomerID = Cells(currentrow, 1) Then
        'find last number that applies
        serialno = serialno + 1
    End If
    're-assign customerID with new serial number
CustomerID = CountryCode & CustomerCode & serialno
Next currentrow

Me.lblCustomerID = CustomerID

End Sub
```

And lastly, this is the code from the ActiveX Command Button that brings out the UserForm.

```
Private Sub cmdNCustomerData_Click()

frmCustomerdata.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you actually call `FindCustomerID`?

Comment: If the buttons are not on the form you will need to refer to the form. `Me` will refer to the sheet. But I could be misunderstanding.

Comment: I would take the `If count = 0 Then ... End If` outside the loop (i.e. after the loop)

Comment: Because you added the ActiveX button in a separate sheet the line `If lCustomerID = Cells(currentrow, 1) Then` is accessing `Cells(currentrow, 1)` of that sheet. You basically forgot a `.` The line should be `If lCustomerID = .Cells(currentrow, 1) Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem you described is a missing `.` to qualify `Cells(currentrow, 1)`. Because you added the ActiveX button to a different sheet, the line

```
If lCustomerID = Cells(currentrow, 1) Then
```

accesses `Cells(currentrow, 1)` of that sheet. To fix this the range needs to be qualified with a `.` to become

```
If lCustomerID = .Cells(currentrow, 1) Then
```

I would also take

```
If count = 0 Then
.
.
.
End If
```

outside the loop. You are repeating these lines many times unnecessarily.

The first block of code then becomes:

```
Private Sub cmdAddNewCustomer_Click()
Dim count As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lCustomerID As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Customer Data")
'find first empty row in database
lrow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", searchorder:=xlRows, _
    Searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    
lCustomerID = txtCustomerID

count = 0

With ws
    ' Count backward to delete rows completely
    For currentrow = lrow - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If lCustomerID = .Cells(currentrow, 1) Then
           count = count + 1
        End If
    
        If count > 1 Then
            .Cells(currentrow, 1).Resize(1, 14).ClearContents
            ' Uncomment the following line to delete the whole row completely
            '.Rows(currentrow).Delete
        End If
    
    Next currentrow
    
    If count > 1 Then
        MsgBox (count - 1 " duplicates of CustomerID found and cleared!")
    ElseIf count = 0 Then
        .Cells(lrow, 1).Value = Me.txtCustomerID.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 2).Value = Me.txtCustomerName.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 3).Value = Me.cboCustomerStatus.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 4).Value = Me.txtContactPerson.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 5).Value = Me.cboDepartment.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 6).Value = Me.txtPosition.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 7).Value = Me.cboRoleType.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 8).Value = Me.txtofficeHP1.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 9).Value = Me.txtOfficeHP2.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 10).Value = Me.txtMobileHP1.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 11).Value = Me.txtMobileHP2.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 12).Value = Me.txtEmail1.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 13).Value = Me.txtEmail2.Value
        .Cells(lrow, 14).Value = Me.txtEmail3.Value
    End If
End With
'clear the data
Me.txtCustomerName.Value = ""
Me.cboCustomerStatus.Value = ""
Me.txtContactPerson.Value = ""
Me.cboDepartment.Value = ""
Me.txtPosition.Value = ""
Me.cboRoleType.Value = ""
Me.txtofficeHP1.Value = ""
Me.txtOfficeHP2.Value = ""
Me.txtMobileHP1.Value = ""
Me.txtMobileHP2.Value = ""
Me.txtEmail1.Value = ""
Me.txtEmail2.Value = ""
Me.txtEmail3.Value = ""

End Sub
```

In the `FindCustomerID` subroutine you have exactly the same problem with the line

```
If CustomerID = Cells(currentrow, 1) Then
```

as `Cells(currentrow, 1)` is not qualified and therefore, should become

```
If CustomerID = ws.Cells(currentrow, 1) Then
```

You are also reassigning the `CustomerID` many times unnecessarily. I would take the reassignment inside the `If` statement and the loop will become

```
For currentrow = 2 To lastrow
    If CustomerID = ws.Cells(currentrow, 1) Then
        'find last number that applies
        serialno = serialno + 1
        're-assign customerID with new serial number
        CustomerID = CountryCode & CustomerCode & serialno
    End If
Next currentrow
```

This way `CustomerID` is only reassigned if and only if `serialno` changes.

Comment: This works !! Thank you so much for helping me out!